# std::unique_ptr with array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl

Is this safe?

```
std::unique_ptr<A> ptr(new A[100]);
```

When `ptr` goes out of scope and its destructor called, will it incorrectly `delete` the pointer, or `delete[]` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to correctly specify the type the `unique_ptr` will be holding for it to work correctly:

```
std::unique_ptr<A[]> ptr(new A[100]);
```

This will default to a deleter that uses `delete[]` instead of `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

If you correctly specify the pointed-to type as `A[]` it will correctly `delete[]` the pointer because there is a template specialization of `unique_ptr` for array types.

Note that you would not have had the opportunity to go wrong here if the type could be automatically inferred. That would require the expression that produces the pointer to be a function call (in the same vein as `std::make_pair`), like this:

```
auto ptr = make_unique(new A[100]);
```

This is a useful utility that's missing from C++11, but it has been added to C++14.